# How to share a table between multiple Postgresql databases

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, authentication, database-schema

My web app has multiple deployments -- each is a unique site with a unique URL.
Each deployment has different data, UI, etc. but a very similar Postgresql database structure (with PostGIS).  The databases all live on the same DB server.  I would like users from 1 deployment to be able to log in to all other deployed apps without having to re-register.

What I want is a single "users" table that is shared across multiple app databases.  Any user who registers in one app should be recognized by all other apps.
Is this possible with Postgres?  Are schemas the way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, schemas are the solution. Use a single PostgreSQL cluster, with a single database.

Create a group for all of app users:

```
CREATE ROLE app;
```

Create global "app" schema, where all global shared applications tables will live.

```
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION app;
CREATE TABLE app.objects ( objectid int PRIMARY KEY );
ALTER TABLE app.objects OWNER TO app;
```

Create separate user (with no superuser rights) for each of deployments:

```
CREATE USER app01 IN ROLE app;
CREATE USER app02 IN ROLE app;
```

Optionally, instead of `IN ROLE app`, you can grant explicit rights for these users on selected app objects:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA app TO app01;
GRANT SELECT on app.objects TO app01;
```

Create private schemas, where deployment-dependent tables will live:

```
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION app01; 
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION app02;
```

Now you have a private schema for every application deployed; but at the same time you have shared access to global data.

What's nice, is that application does not have to be schema-aware. `SELECT * FROM froobles` will by default resolve to `SELECT * FROM app01.froobles`, if you are connected as `app01` user. You do not have to specify schema name.

As an extra measure, you can use table inheritance to extend global objects on per-deployment basis:

```
CREATE TABLE app01.objects (
  localattr1 int,
  localattr2 text
)
INHERITS ( app.objects );
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks filiprem.  From messing with schemas, I'd figured out a bit of this but your solution is very comprehensive and seems to be just what I need.  Will implement now!

Comment: The idea is really interesting ....
... but it seems don't works ...
The inherited table don't "see" global data .... (it's empty)

Comment: @NCister - but this is expected. Master table (app.objects) should see partition data. Partition table (app01.objects) will not see master data. Only own data.

Comment: You are right !
Is there a way to share data between tables (... same table) created in different schema (... respecting autoincrement Primary Key ...) ?

Answer (score 4):

The answer of filiprem is awesome.. However, I found that I needed to set up the paths also for the users `app01`, `app02`:

```
ALTER USER app01 SET SEARCH_PATH TO "$user",app;
ALTER USER app02 SET SEARCH_PATH TO "$user",app;
```

Also if you need that the role `app` to have access to the tables in the schemas app01, app02, you would need this code:

```
-- grant all future tables
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA app01 GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO app;

-- grant all existing tables
GRANT SELECT 
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA app01
TO app
```

Instead of `SELECT` you can have other privileges. The same for user `app02`.

**Update:** In order to be able for the user `app` to select rows in `app01` schema, it  needs at least `USAGE` privilege for the schema `app01` (along with table privilege `SELECT` defined above):

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA app01 TO app;
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [dblink](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html).

Comment: Thanks Branko.  I should have noted that the databases all currently live on the same server so perhaps dblink is overkill?